# How to use Thunderbolt Display with Laptop

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display, video-adapter

I am currently using my 2015 MacBook Pro with my thunderbolt display. I want to buy a new laptop (HP) but I realized that I would have some problems to connect it to the Thunderbolt display. The new HP I want to buy has an HDMI port. I have browsed on internet where I could find a HDMI male to Thunderbolt 2 female (because I have an integrated Thunderbolt cable with the display) and there is nothing even on Amazon. I could only find adaptators with Thunderbolt male. I have searched for another way to connect the display with my new PC. On the backside, there is a Thunderbolt 2 port. Can I use this port to connect a Thunderbolt 2 to HDMI adaptator ? If you know another way I could use the integrated cable, please tell me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of connecting to the TB Display: either using the built-in 'male' cable, or the TB port on the back. Both are "miniDisplayPort" connectors, and can function as 'dumb' video connectors if you can get some connection from your laptop (USB-C, HDMI, etc) to a miniDisplayPort connector (either male or female).

If you are connecting via a non-Thunderbolt connection, then you won't get all the Thunderbolt goodness of the speakers, extra ports, webcam, etc.

Comment: My HP does not has TB port ! That is the problem. But if I use the TB2 port on the display backside, will it work ? I know that I will not get webcam, speakers... but even now with my Mac Book Pro (that has TB2), the camera and display headphones are not working so....

Comment: If you can get a cable from <something on your HP> to miniDisplayPort, and plug it into the TB port on the back on the Display, that should work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will use HDMI on my HP. But I have read on internet that mini display port was not compatible with TB2 displays. I have also read that mini DisplayPort cables were not fully compatible with the TB2 technology. I am not understanding... Thanks for your help

Comment: There is also another problem. When I browse on Amazon, Google and High Techs sites, I find cable that allows only the DP to be a source and the HDMI an output. Does the HDMI input to TB2 output technology exists ?

Comment: The Thunderbolt Port IS MiniDisplayPort. The Display is TB1, not 2.

Comment: I understand !! But I am saying  the cables I found (and I have searched for quite an hour) are not bi-directional and the manufacturers insist on this because it was on some products pictures. The cables only allows that the Mini Display Port is used as an input and the HDMI an output for connecting a TV or something else. The problem is that I want the HDMI port to be an input and the Mini DP an output connected to my display.

Comment: I understand !! But I am saying the cables I found (and I have searched for quite an hour) are not bi-directional and the manufacturers insist on this because it was on some products pictures. The cables only allows that the Mini Display Port is used as an input and the HDMI an output for connecting a TV or something else. The problem is that I want the HDMI port to be an input and the Mini DP an output connected to my display.